# Как предотвратить переполнение базы данных?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование

Имеется БД. Она предназначена для хранения информации о пользователях. Каждому пользователю даётся 9-значный id и пароль в сопоставление. Каким образом можно предотвратить намеренное переполнение базы данных (злоумышленники создадут ботнет и будут слать множество запросов регистрации всё новых пользователей)? Какой дополнительный параметр нужно использовать помимо id и пароля?

Comment: Вот прочитайте про `CAPTCHA`  для блокировки ботов, давно придумано.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0

Comment: Добавь в форме поле где регистрирующемуся нужно будет посчитать производную

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan: Что-то при установке RMS Host никакой капчи не выходит... А ведь там всё тоже самое. Есть хост, есть id, есть какое-то ключевое слово, по которому проводится его аутентификация. Как же RMS защиту реализует от подобных нападок?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich: Слишком жёстко) Капча в таком случае. Но вот по поводу даже её у меня вопрос возникает (следуя из моего комментария выше).